# Allowing a third party website to save to my drive (and with no sharing permission)

Tags: google-drive-api

We're working on an app to sell our music and was wondering if Google Drive can be used as an online storage solution.

The user would complete the transaction on our site, and then authorize us to save the file (or multiple files) to their Google Drive.

The appeal to us is to solve downloading problems via the browser. I believe the Google Drive api returns a successful response when the delivery is complete. If incomplete, we would then either resend or update.

One other requirement is whether we can set permissions to not allow sharing after save (and for that setting to be permanent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do everything you want. The last part about not allowing users to reshare, you can do this if you still own the file, but cannot do it if you have made the user own the file. I am not sure you could ever achieve that - a user can always download a file and share it themselves, whether you are using Drive or your own custom system.